# Black Screen and cleaning the code (LibGDX)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm following video tutorials using libGdx and kinda adapting the code to get what I want. I managed to draw the HUD and an animation, but when I tried to add a button following another tutorial I ended with a black screen, here is the code:

```
public class WorldRenderer implements ApplicationListener, Screen {

Pixmap pixmap;
SpriteBatch batch;
private Skin skin;
private Stage stage;
OrthographicCamera cam;
Table table;
TextButton buttonShake;
BitmapFont white;
BitmapFont black;
private TextureAtlas atlas;
Texture virusTexture;

Texture hudTexture;
private static final float HUD_WIDTH = 480f;
private static final float HUD_HEIGHT = 800f;
private static final float WALK_ANIM_WIDTH = 337f;
private static final float WALK_ANIM_HEIGHT = 213f;
public static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 480;
public static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800;


private static final int FRAME_COLS = 2; 
private static final int FRAME_ROWS = 2; 

Animation walkAnimation; 
Texture walkSheet;
TextureRegion[] walkFrames;

TextureRegion currentFrame;

float stateTime;


float width, height;
Hud hud;



public WorldRenderer(World world) {
    this.world = world;

    walkSheet = new Texture("data/character.png"); 
    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheet,
            walkSheet.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS, walkSheet.getHeight()
                    / FRAME_ROWS); 
    walkFrames = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFrames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
        }
    }
    walkAnimation = new Animation(0.25f, walkFrames); 

    stateTime = 0f;

    width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    cam = new OrthographicCamera(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    cam.position.set(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2f, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2f, 0);


    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);



    hudTexture = new Texture("data/hud.png");
    hudTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);


}

public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    cam.update();
    stage.act(delta);


    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true); 


    hud = world.getHud();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(hudTexture, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2f - HUD_WIDTH / 2f,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2f - HUD_HEIGHT / 2f);

    batch.draw(currentFrame, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2f - WALK_ANIM_WIDTH / 2f,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2f - WALK_ANIM_HEIGHT / 2f); 


    batch.end();
    stage.draw();



}

public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    virusTexture.dispose();
    hudTexture.dispose();
    skin.dispose();
    atlas.dispose();
    white.dispose();
    black.dispose();
    stage.dispose();

}

@Override
public void create() {

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void render() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

I'm pretty sure you are also going to find unused lines of code so please point them out for me if you want so I can better organize my code and learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible problem is that you implement an ApplicationListener and a Screen, both have the render method and almost the same methods.

You shouldn't implement both. If this is your app entry-point I would go for the applicationListener.

However, for the educational purpose you should read some topics about the Game class as your next app entry-point. Consider using separated "screens" that handle the render part and a "brain" that allows them to communicate with each other, this is where the Game class becomes handy.

Things can seem a little trickier at the beginning but will definitely make sense to you after a bit of studying ;)